# After updating pod, I got this error. Invalid UIAccessibilityTraits 'tab'

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native-tab-view. I'm not sure this has something to do with this error.

```
 <TabView
            bounces={false}
            navigationState={this.state}
            swipeEnabled={false}
            renderScene={() => null}
            renderTabBar={props => (
              <TabBar
                {...props}
                indicatorStyle={{
                  backgroundColor: "#212121",
                  height: "100%",
                  width: "38%",
                  marginLeft: "5%"
                }}
                style={{ backgroundColor: "#FFD54F" }}
                inactiveColor="#757575"
                activeColor={"#212121"}
                pressOpacity={0.9}
                tabStyle={{
                  backgroundColor: "#FFD54F",
                  marginBottom: 3
                }}
                labelStyle={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}
              />
            )}
            onIndexChange={index => this.setState({ index })}
            initialLayout={{
              width: Dimensions.get("window").width
            }}
          />
          {pages}
```

Above code worked before updating.

This error occurs when I enter the screen using react-native-tab-view.

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Can you please post your some code /

Comment: @KishanBharda I posted my code. please check this.

Comment: May be this issue will help you. https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view/issues/955 it says you have to install dependency 2.11.0.

Comment: You mean,  do I need to install react-native-tab-view@2.11.0. ?

Comment: It's working! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Great. Can you post solution as answer so it helps to others ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was version issue. I just re-installed react-native-tab-view@2.11.0. and it worked! I hope this would be useful to others!

Comment: Any 2.XX.XX Version would work. There is a problem with the pod I guess.